# Generating Date and Column data from a list between two dates (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, date, range

I have a set of data I need to fill some gaps in. I cant just use a DateTable as I need a location to be included.

I would need to select all the room numbers (Select roomnum from rooms) and generate a table with the date range for each room.

What the table looks like with the missing Dates/Rooms

```
Date        Room  Occupents
2016-05-11  100   2
2016-05-11  102   2
2016-05-12  102   1
2016-05-12  104   3
2016-05-12  105   1
2016-05-13  101   2
```

The Reference Table I would like to build between two dates.

```
Date        Room  
2016-05-11  100
2016-05-11  101  
2016-05-11  102
2016-05-11  103  
2016-05-11  104  
2016-05-11  105
2016-05-12  100
2016-05-12  101  
2016-05-12  102
2016-05-12  104
2016-05-12  105
2016-05-13  100
2016-05-13  101
2016-05-13  102
2016-05-13  103
2016-05-13  104
2016-05-13  105
```

I was hoping to be able to create the reference table without a cursor. Anyone have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @Table table (Date date,Room varchar(10),Occupents int)
Insert into @Table (Date,Room,Occupents) values 
('2016-05-11','100',2),
('2016-05-11','102',2),
('2016-05-12','102',1),
('2016-05-12','104',3),
('2016-05-12','105',1),
('2016-05-13','101',2)

Select Date,Room 
 From (Select Distinct Date from @Table) A
 Join (Select Distinct Room from @Table) B on 1=1
 Order by 1,2
```

Returns

```
Date        Room
2016-05-11  100
2016-05-11  101
2016-05-11  102
2016-05-11  104
2016-05-11  105
2016-05-12  100
2016-05-12  101
2016-05-12  102
2016-05-12  104
2016-05-12  105
2016-05-13  100
2016-05-13  101
2016-05-13  102
2016-05-13  104
2016-05-13  105
```

Comment: Missing Data for room 103 which would have been pulled in from the rooms table, which may have not been used that week but still needs to be accounted for.

Comment: There was no room 103 in your supplied data.  The quick fix would be Select Distinct Room from [Your Room Def Table]

Comment: I should add if you want a complete user defined date range (i.e. no gaps and not dependent on occupant data) you may want Select distinct date from [A Date Table]  where date between X and Y.   Or I can post a UDF which generates any defined date range